# Get attribute from xml root node with php

Tags: php, xml

I need to get attributes from an XML root node using PHP.  I need to get the number from total, start and count from the `<result>` root node below and assign them as variable in PHP.

```
Ex.    $total, $start, $count

<result total="26" start="0" count="10">
<job>
<title>
<![CDATA[ Rep-Retail Sales, Orange County ]]>
</title>
<date>2014-07-12T00:56:17Z</date>
<onclick>j2c_view(1451827617,2834554843,611926905)</onclick>
<company>
<![CDATA[ Verizon Wireless ]]>
</company>
<city>Laguna Niguel, CA</city>
<description>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `attributes()` method to access them. Example:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xml_string);
$root_attributes = $xml->attributes();
$total = $root_attributes->total;
$start = $root_attributes->start;
$count = $root_attributes->count;

echo "$total, $start, $count"; // 26, 0, 10
```

Answer (score 0):

DOM + Xpath works for that.

```
$xml = '<result total="26" start="0" count="10"/>';

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXml($xml);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);

var_dump(
  $total = $xpath->evaluate('number(/*/@total)'),
  $start = $xpath->evaluate('number(/*/@start)'),
  $count = $xpath->evaluate('number(/*/@count)')
);
```